# How can I get depth values?

Tags: ros, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the ubuntu 11.10 and openni driver.

I want to know depth values about my kinect image.

How can I get or see depth values(distances)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41894/how-can-i-get-depth-values?/) by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[REP-0118](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0118.html) explains the depth image interface.

Assuming you are using the `openni_launch` package, the topics published are [documented here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch#Published_Topics). From what you asked, you probably want one of these:

- `/camera/depth/image`
- `/camera/depth/points`

The `image` is a 2D depth matrix containing floating point distances in meters. The `points` are a 3D point cloud in the camera's frame of reference (`/camera_depth_optical_frame`).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0